# Visual studio reinstalls apps when re-running with no changes

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, nuget-package

I’m having a problem when debugging my Android app. When I start debugging, then stop, then start debugging again, it will always re-install the app on the phone even though there hasn’t been any changes done. This can start being a pain since our app is large and each build takes over a minute to complete. As far as I can tell, I’ve set everything correctly, including having Fast Deployment turned on and having the linker disabled to speed up the build process but it still rebuilds, uninstalls and reinstalls the app, taking up a lot of time. One thing to note is that we don't see this behavior in Xamarin Studio on the mac, it’s only within Visual Studio.

I’m running visual studio 2015 14.0.25123 update2 with
Xamarin Android 6.0.3.5 (a94a03b).

Please help me resolve this issue.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the information you've provided, it seems like you're hitting a recent issue we've seen with NuGet packages and dating. The new NuGet client for Visual Studio will now honour the dates found inside of the .nupkg, instead of using the current date when writing files to disk.

What this means is that packages with odd dates in their files, like the popular ModernHttpClient library (which dates its files using 2046) will end up written in disk with those dates. As a result of this, msbuild will detect this future date upon build and assume your app is not up to date and will then fire a complete rebuild, essentially breaking incremental build support.

You can check that this is the case by turning on msbuild diagnostic output. The very first line in the build output pad should read something like:

`1>Project 'App3' is not up to date. Input file 'c:\temp\app3\packages\modernhttpclient.2.4.2\lib\monoandroid\okhttp.dll' is modified after output file 'C:\temp\App3\App3\bin\Debug\App3.pdb'.`

To fix it, you can touch the date of the offending .dll to the current date or download the NuGet packlage from the NuGet website, then extract using Windows built-in .zip support (you must use the Windows built-in support other utilities may keep the bogus dates).

The following VS extension was also created to automatically touch the dates of offending packages and is definitely the easiest way to get things sorted:
https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/0ffd5d55-6d03-4be1-95b5-a94c89af86ba

Do note that this issue does not manifest if you're using Xamarin Studio.